# URL trying to scrape loads a different page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/event/179665865?category=odds&subcategory=player-props however my code wasn't working and when I troubleshot it I realized it was taking me to the original page at https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/event/179665865 The first link is a tab within the second link.

Here is the code of a tester I created to check to see if I was scraping the correct page.

```
import re
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


request = urllib.request.Request("https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/event/179665865?category=odds&subcategory=player-props")
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

my_list = []
links = soup.find_all("div", class_="sportsbook-table__body")
for link in links:
    my_list.append(link)
print(my_list[0].prettify())
```

This code prints the HTML from https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/event/179665865 and not the URL I entered: https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/event/179665865?category=odds&subcategory=player-props
Any ideas on how to find a solution?

Here is my original code:

```
import re
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/leagues/football/3"
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
nfl_html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(nfl_html, "html.parser")
nfl_table = soup.find("div", {"class":"sportsbook-offer-category-card"})
game_links = nfl_table.find_all("a", {"class":"event-cell-link"})

#Extracting links of all NFL games 
extracted_links = []
for link in game_links:
    url = "https://sportsbook.draftkings.com" + link["href"]
    extracted_links.append(url)
unique_links = list(set(extracted_links))

#Extracting links for player props tab
pp_link_list = []
for link in unique_links:
    url = link
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    game_html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(game_html, "html.parser")
    player_prop_string = soup.find("a", attrs={"href":re.compile(".player-props")})
    player_prop_link = player_prop_string.get("href")
    cleaned_pp_link = "https://sportsbook.draftkings.com" + player_prop_link
    pp_link_list.append(cleaned_pp_link)

#finding Receptions tag
for link in pp_link_list:
    request = urllib.request.Request(link)
    receptions_html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(receptions_html, "html.parser")
    pp_receptions = soup.find("a", string="Receptions")
    print(pp_receptions)
```

Here is the code from the tutorial for scraping JavaScript:

```
import requests

url = "https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/seo/event/179665865?category=odds&subcategory=player-props"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
  'Referer': 'https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/event/179665865?category=odds&subcategory=player-props',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'Cookie': '_abck=DBDA89A5A31D9FEFB47C67D719658B43~-1~YAAQHfs7F5OGUJN2AQAAYA/mlgXT6aeFPsQvZz54rGwtk/Ly825VmhBkHjVKfgFl8zCTUQ2Y3nJiNrOn6DX4jJkGA/YJaYwCKG+PUE1dwqmD9QW4x7DXO8s9u9zcS+RcPVakt/wbmEBxoM4tEmWsTpnjz+EW9s9NgW97dezt5ap1hEjFpMCTsa56T+q9RfuZKdSC/K7Gdps6hYt/FWb39j24XVIXTlLXvplE0btKZ+LyFb6bSJCM6prARRjZzR4N2ZnKq4unE/LIDIWJSKMDJ0DZ1SJmpy4WufraZS65EHphBXAU8rmuwJxkc6/f7g==~-1~-1~-1; _gcl_aw=GCL.1608849430.Cj0KCQiAlZH_BRCgARIsAAZHSBnmRt0mLw0NxfWBSTiF25LMSMbn6sNxhOyCIxazxiXoeZJeKtnRRWsaAlCPEALw_wcB; _gcl_dc=GCL.1608849430.Cj0KCQiAlZH_BRCgARIsAAZHSBnmRt0mLw0NxfWBSTiF25LMSMbn6sNxhOyCIxazxiXoeZJeKtnRRWsaAlCPEALw_wcB; _gcl_au=1.1.1388899746.1608849430; ken_gclid=Cj0KCQiAlZH_BRCgARIsAAZHSBnmRt0mLw0NxfWBSTiF25LMSMbn6sNxhOyCIxazxiXoeZJeKtnRRWsaAlCPEALw_wcB; _ga=GA1.2.1743418995.1608849430; _gac_UA-28146424-9=1.1608849430.Cj0KCQiAlZH_BRCgARIsAAZHSBnmRt0mLw0NxfWBSTiF25LMSMbn6sNxhOyCIxazxiXoeZJeKtnRRWsaAlCPEALw_wcB; _gac_UA-28146424-14=1.1608849430.Cj0KCQiAlZH_BRCgARIsAAZHSBnmRt0mLw0NxfWBSTiF25LMSMbn6sNxhOyCIxazxiXoeZJeKtnRRWsaAlCPEALw_wcB; ab.storage.deviceId.b543cb99-2762-451f-9b3e-91b2b1538a42=%7B%22g%22%3A%2252f3867a-5f17-3c2e-94bd-5d3249f64d04%22%2C%22c%22%3A1608849430261%2C%22l%22%3A1608849430261%7D; _scid=64979b4d-306e-49e8-882b-376874a71712; _fbp=fb.1.1608849430431.2041993013; _csrf=e296fdf6-e4e5-45f9-bee0-50903c5b6c43; clientDateOffset=300; __helocckid=60b2e760-1d5a-f092-2d2b-182e5d900410; _ga=GA1.3.1743418995.1608849430; quickStartWelcomeModalHidden=1; _gid=GA1.2.1425230282.1611114838; _gid=GA1.3.1425230282.1611114838; _sctr=1|1611032400000; bm_sz=CE022114B11530B2AA11F32C83D2F5E0~YAAQlADARR2NnvV2AQAA6mmxIQq4vlc3GPjcRNuA2sgi8hzL4xa/VmvykJ2OzqJ2MOAaYkOZGi2jSasJGdaOKMNZxmaCuIuFI/+68dSFNeuXsli3tilqlsTTLAYADbMtRAkr/mvrNXVNnB2xyeLtw2Z1QMTrpr3dgKbu/s8yKJJmqM23CI/3T2JDFmESDLIA/hGt; STIDN=eyJDIjoxMjIzNTQ4NTIzLCJTIjoxNjA0NTA0MTkxNiwiU1MiOjE2NjI1MzE1OTM1LCJWIjo4NDA3NjA4OTYxLCJMIjoxLCJFIjoiMjAyMS0wMS0yMVQwMDo1ODo0MS4wMDI3MjEyWiIsIlNFIjoiVVMtREsiLCJVQSI6IkFMQkN1MEZKRm0xOEJ4NkI1NVNEaG5DV2x4RWhZUnpoeS8xbTVHYTRhcm89IiwiREsiOiI0MDI2MDRiNi1mNzUxLTQzYjgtYWUzYy03NWE2MTA3ODEyYjAiLCJESSI6IjlkOWUwNDkyLTk3MmQtNGViMi04NzM4LWQ1ZmE4NjI2ODZmNSIsIkREIjoyMTc1MDY4NTUyfQ==; STH=25ed8076576d85fd5e714c743efafe863bbe9992636279042f125bf814876dc7; ak_bmsc=33918B58D43253116BF830CEFC5451F445C000AC83470000B9CA08603E37D434~plrtxo6LJtZGvCmFfba4SxJsiH+bYXoseg9EFP0ePzvm+9kiIjRZAxGl3IDBrYamORXt8uj/+iHuOah3l5BHYRebUS7QBaQLEBVGlJ1UaJGXFrYmxZcnRPGUK9yD0iapDGlEWW+iobTsAAnH6UtLK0G6GykGGTeID3GobdlNanXSP/K8StTpNEonGFATgQi659nVloFHWXsyZoSLz6JUv7HqcQGuLfwH/s+CxSzoRTrtw=; hgg=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.apqbLQnG0Nj66-jWAZ09AaCUlNyu43O3rx9NsJcOiQE; _tq_id.TV-54368172-1.fee2=87ca359129cec881.1608849430.0.1611188941..; ab.storage.sessionId.b543cb99-2762-451f-9b3e-91b2b1538a42=%7B%22g%22%3A%22972cb2fe-319b-613b-c9a5-8ede2f1f01ae%22%2C%22e%22%3A1611190741949%2C%22c%22%3A1611188920508%2C%22l%22%3A1611188941949%7D; _uetsid=203570505ad311eb8977a502002b06fb; _uetvid=18d28b90552911eba93ba9fa3de3ddaf; STE="2021-01-21T01:24:07.3520115Z"; bm_sv=97E74E999901A3F2FF1DB0E898B535E8~p/KKtKWD42o7AL6FLvDZyMDzEMufDsjtAh27f1gyY2b28U6tONfYNoQvOsTRMFumXdxleL7cjyt/4QKs4wbPBII2EtIGHMsyVk6ARUqTvVaLmW+OoJsx5+DPSJqDGCE/LvHqS5qfW9tFYR67+M3Y9W/ngCy4e7RQsVSDXudsEH4=; _gat_UA-28146424-9=1; _gat_UA-28146424-14=1',
  'If-None-Match': 'W/"1c-vSZYn6NdKuXhr7+6ybkEI0KDIh8"'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: do you just want the player prop table, or all the table under the tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```py
import re
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


request = urllib.request.Request("https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/event/179665865?category=odds&subcategory=player-props")
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

my_list = []
# links = soup.find_all("div", class_="sportsbook-table__body")
links = soup.select('a.event-cell-link')
for link in links:
    my_list.append(link.attrs['href'])
print(my_list)
```

If this is what you are looking for, then you are very close, you just need a new selector `a.event-cell-link` and use `BeautifulSoup.select()` to get the links.

Hope that helps. Feel free to ask any further questions.

---

Edit #1:

To your additional question - some part of the page would be populated with javascript. I'll give you a piece of code that you might find helpful:

```py
import re
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


request = urllib.request.Request("https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/event/179665865?category=odds&subcategory=player-props")
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()

data_lines = html.decode("utf-8").splitlines()

for line in data_lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith('window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = '):
        json_str = line.replace('window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ', '')[:-1]
        json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
print(json_dict.keys())

# dict_keys(['eventGroups', 'error', 'outcomes', 'sports', 'displayGroup', 'offers', 'settings', 'loading', 'quickLinks', 'strapline', 'featured', 'user', 'event', 'modals', 'experiments', 'rewards', 'myBets', 'seo', 'promotions', 'userOptedInPromotions', 'carouselCards', 'betslip', 'teamPages', 'playoffPages'])
```

Now you can work with the dict. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey Daniel, the second part of my code was just trying to print the first "box" on the page to see if I was in the "Popular" tab or the "Player Props" tab. My goal is to scrape the Player Props tab but it seems the page only loads the Popular tab regardless of the URL I input. I'm hoping to scrape the "Receptions" box within the Player Props tab for more clarity.

Comment: Please look at the edited version and see if it makes sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still relatively new to learning Python. I do see now that some of the page is javascript and attempted to follow instructions for scraping it here: https://www.danielms.site/blog/web-scraping-javascript-with-python-xhr/ I was able to walkthrough the tutorial and get a block of code but am unsure how to implement it into my own. (I just added that code into my original question). For your answer, I'm also not sure what to make of it. Apologies again, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could pull out the json string within the html, or just get the json from the api. Either way, you'll need to iterate thriugh to parse it. It is a nested json, so it can be tricky (especially for someone new/learning), but possible to do:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://sportsbook.draftkings.com//sites/US-SB/api/v1/event/179665865'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'includePromotions': 'true',
'format': 'json'}

data = requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=payload).json()
events = data['eventCategories']

rows = []
for event in events:
    row = {}
    name = event['name']
    row['name'] = name

    componentizedOffers = event['componentizedOffers']
    for each in componentizedOffers:
        subcategoryName = each['subcategoryName']
        row['subcategoryName'] = subcategoryName
        
        offers = each['offers']
        for offer in offers:
            for play in offer:
                offers_label = play['label']
                row['offers.label'] = offers_label
                
                outcomes = play['outcomes']
                for outcome in outcomes:
                    for key in outcome.keys():
                        if key not in ['providerOutcomeId', 'providerId', 'providerOfferId']:
                            row[key] = outcome[key]
                
                    rows.append(row.copy())
            

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output (of first 25 rows):**

```
print (df.head(25).to_string())
       name   subcategoryName      offers.label              label oddsAmerican  oddsDecimal oddsFractional  line        participant criterionName
0   Popular              Game      Point Spread      TB Buccaneers         -117         1.86          17/20   3.5      TB Buccaneers           NaN
1   Popular              Game      Point Spread         GB Packers         -105         1.96          19/20  -3.5         GB Packers           NaN
2   Popular              Game      Total Points               Over         -112         1.90           9/10  51.0         GB Packers           NaN
3   Popular              Game      Total Points              Under         -109         1.92          10/11  51.0         GB Packers           NaN
4   Popular              Game         Moneyline      TB Buccaneers         +150         2.50            6/4  51.0      TB Buccaneers           NaN
5   Popular              Game         Moneyline         GB Packers         -175         1.58            4/7  51.0         GB Packers           NaN
6   Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer      Davante Adams         +525         6.25           21/4  51.0      Davante Adams         First
7   Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer      Davante Adams         +525         6.25           21/4  51.0      Davante Adams          Last
8   Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer      Davante Adams         -182         1.55          11/20  51.0      Davante Adams      To Score
9   Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer        Aaron Jones         +850         9.50           17/2  51.0        Aaron Jones         First
10  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer        Aaron Jones         +850         9.50           17/2  51.0        Aaron Jones          Last
11  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer        Aaron Jones         +115         2.15          23/20  51.0        Aaron Jones      To Score
12  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer         Mike Evans        +1000        11.00           10/1  51.0         Mike Evans         First
13  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer         Mike Evans        +1000        11.00           10/1  51.0         Mike Evans          Last
14  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer         Mike Evans         +135         2.35          27/20  51.0         Mike Evans      To Score
15  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer      Robert Tonyan        +1100        12.00           11/1  51.0      Robert Tonyan         First
16  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer      Robert Tonyan        +1100        12.00           11/1  51.0      Robert Tonyan          Last
17  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer      Robert Tonyan         +150         2.50            6/4  51.0      Robert Tonyan      To Score
18  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer       Chris Godwin        +1200        13.00           12/1  51.0       Chris Godwin         First
19  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer       Chris Godwin        +1200        13.00           12/1  51.0       Chris Godwin          Last
20  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer       Chris Godwin         +165         2.65          33/20  51.0       Chris Godwin      To Score
21  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer  Leonard Fournette        +1300        14.00           13/1  51.0  Leonard Fournette         First
22  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer  Leonard Fournette        +1300        14.00           13/1  51.0  Leonard Fournette          Last
23  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer  Leonard Fournette         +190         2.90          19/10  51.0  Leonard Fournette      To Score
24  Popular  Touchdown Scorer  Touchdown Scorer       Allen Lazard        +1400        15.00           14/1  51.0       Allen Lazard         First
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This is definitely a bit over my head, but a great starting point to work from. A key part of the code I'm trying to build is being able to start at the home page of DraftKings and crawl to the NFL page to iterate through each of games that way I don't have to manually enter the URL. So my question is, how did you generate the URL in the code you posted and is there a way to generate that link through code? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @travis_c18, sorry just seeing this now for some reason. I'll have to take a look, but normally in an API, there'll be a standard endpoint (url) to use. And from there you can build off it to get dynamic things like and event ID and such. It's going to be tough to test with NFL (unless I can find some documentation) as obviously there's only 1 game left in the season.